# How to replace a given item in a list?

Tags: list, scala

This describes the problem pretty well:

```
scala> var l2 = List(1,2,3)
l2: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)

scala> l2(2) = 55
<console>:10: error: value update is not a member of List[Int]
              l2(2) = 55
              ^
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`scala.List` is *immutable*, meaning you cannot update it in place. If you want to create a *copy* of your List which contains the updated mapping, you can do the following:

```
val updated = l2.updated( 2, 55 )
```

There are mutable ordered sequence types as well, in `scala.collection.mutable`, such as `Buffer` types which seem more like what you want. If you try the following you should have more success:

```
scala> import scala.collection._
import scala.collection._
scala> val b = mutable.Buffer(1,2,3)
b: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 3)
scala> b(2) = 55
scala> b
res1: scala.collection.mutable.Buffer[Int] = ArrayBuffer(1, 2, 55)
```

Edit: Just to note that some other answers have mentioned that you should use a "mutable List type" - this is true, but "List" in Scala just refers to the single-linked list, whereas in Java it's generally used for any ordered, random-access collection. There is also a `DoubleLinkedList`, which is more like a Java `LinkedList`, and a `MutableList`, which is a type used for the internals of some other types.

Generally speaking what you probably want in Scala is a `Buffer` for this job; especially since the default implementation is an `ArrayBuffer`, which is pretty close to being the same as `ArrayList`, most peoples' default, in Java.

If you ever want to find out what the closest "mapping" of a Java collections interface to the Scala world is, though, the easiest thing to do is probably just check what [JavaConversions](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/JavaConversions$.html) does. In this case you can see the mapping is to `Buffer`:

```
scala.collection.mutable.Buffer <=> java.util.List
```

Answer (score 3):

The List you are creating is immutable.

```
scala> val l = List(1,2,3)
l: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
scala> l.getClass
res3: java.lang.Class[_] = class scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon
```

Use a mutable List instead and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks to both but that won't go as I'm working with existing API that has immutable list. I guess then I need to replace entire list be reconstructing it.

Answer (score 3):

But you can wrap the assignment in an implicit if you don't like `updated`

```
 implicit class RichList[A](l: List[A]) {
      def update(which: Int, what: A): List[A] = {
         l.updated(which, what)
      }
 }

 val l = List(1, 2, 3)
 val l2 = l(2) = 55

 List(1, 2, 55)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that Lists in scala are immutable, you need to use a mutable list instead.
Import scala.collection.mutable.Queue and use that instead. Queue is a MutableList, so it should do what you want.

Comment: not necessary to use mutable structure, as noted by Calum above, the updated method returns copy of a List with given element replaced

Answer (score 1):

Lists are immutable in scala. But if you want to replace an element in a List you can use "updated" method like this

```
val num:List[Int]=List(1,5,4,7,8,2,10)
num=num.updated(0,22)
```

Since Lists are immutable,this creates a copy of the first List called num(as we assigned the new list to 'num') by replacing 0th element to 22.So the genaral updated method is

```
listname.updated(index,value)
```

Comment: Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up instead of repeating the same information.

Comment: sorry,This is my first answer in stackoverflow.I wrote what I have understood on "updated" method and I thought it will be usefull to others  plus I didn't have any idea of repeating.Once again sorry for repeating